# Independent tours on two different tabItems in shiny app when using dashboardPage

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `dashboardPage` to build the UI of a shiny app. In this `dashboardPage` I have two `tabItems` (MENU1 and MENU2). Different tasks are carried out in each of these `tabItems` and I need to guide the users through these tasks. To guide the users I have included an `actionButton` for each `tabItem` with a corresponding `observeEvent` in the code below. To this end I used `introBox` and I controlled the steps and intros with `data.step` and `data.intro`, respectively.

Unfortunately, this is not a good solution as the `data.steps` are linked, with a total of 2 steps. In MENU1, when I click on the first `actionButton` I have to complete two steps to finish this tour. In MENU2, when I click on the second `actionButton`, this tour starts in the first step of MENU1.

What I want is one tour for MENU1 and another for MENU2. Any suggestions?

Here my current solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rintrojs)
library(leaflet)

ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "shinyApp"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "MENU1"),
      menuItem("Menu2", tabName = "MENU2")
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem("MENU1",
              fluidRow(
                introjsUI(),
                
                column(3,
                       actionButton("start", "START", class="btn-link")
                )#,
                ),
              fluidRow(
                column(9,
                       fluidRow(
                         column(7,
                                introBox(
                                  actionButton("button1", "Button1"),
                                  data.step=1,
                                  data.intro = wellPanel(
                                    p("Press here, button1")
                                    )
                                  )
                                )
                         )
                       )
                
              )
      ),
      
      tabItem("MENU2",
        fluidRow(
          introjsUI(),
                    column(2,
                           actionButton("start2", "START2", class="btn-link")
                    )

        ),

                fluidRow(
                  column(7,
                         introBox(
                           wellPanel(
                             leafletOutput("mapLocal", width = "100%", height = 600)
                           ),
                           data.step=2,
                           data.intro = wellPanel(
                             p("Press here, button2")
                           )
                         )
                  )
                )
      )
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$start,
               introjs(session))
  
  observeEvent(input$start2,
               introjs(session))
  
  }


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with one tour, but which flips the page before showing the second part. I resorted to some `JavaScript` to add the `beforechange` event. In this event, you can check whether you are about to show your second into step and if this is the case, you can manually trigger the page change by emulating a click on the respective menu item.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rintrojs)

ui<-dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "shinyApp"),
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
         menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "MENU1"),
         menuItem("Menu2", tabName = "MENU2")
      )
   ),
   
   dashboardBody(
      introjsUI(),
      tabItems(
         tabItem("MENU1",
                 fluidRow(
                    actionButton("start", "START", class="btn-link"),
                    introBox(
                       actionButton("button1", "Button1"),
                       data.step = 1,
                       data.intro = wellPanel(
                          p("Press here, button1")
                       )
                    )
                 )
         ),
         tabItem("MENU2",
                 fluidRow(
                    introBox(
                       plotOutput("mapLocal", width = "100%", height = 600),
                       data.step = 2,
                       data.intro = wellPanel(
                          p("Plot Area")
                       )
                    )
                 )
         )
      )
   )
)

js <- paste0("if (targetElement.getAttribute('data-step') === '2') {",
             "$(\"a[data-value='MENU2']\").trigger('click')",
             "}")

server <- function(input, output, session){
   observeEvent(input$start, introjs(session, events = list(onbeforechange = I(js))))
   
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

## Update

While looking into the source code of [rintrojs](https://github.com/carlganz/rintrojs) I figured that there is a `rintrojs` element and this made me curious. After some more searching, I found that the switch panes task is something the creators of  `rintrojs` have already forseen. Thus, the above code can be even further simplified (and is more robust, because we do not have to manually check the tabs):

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
   observeEvent(input$start, introjs(session, 
                events = list(onbeforechange = readCallback("switchTabs"))))
   
}
```